# Container where each item can have multiple non-unique keys (c++17)

Tags: c++, containers, c++17

Image I have this enum class:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3
}
```

And I have a struct/class called MyClass...

Each MyClass object is associated with one or more MyEnum value.

I am wanting a container that will hold MyClass objects, and be able to return a list of all MyClass objects that are associated with a specific MyEnum value when requested. Something a bit like:

```
class Container<std::vector<MyEnum> key, MyClass item> {
public:

    std::vector<MyClass> getMyClassItemListByMyEnumKey(MyEnum enum) {
        return /*code to gather all MyClass items that have the searched MyEnum enum*/;
    }
};
```

I can think of a few ways to do this with questionable efficiency and scalability... But does anyone know of a pre-existing solution to this problem? This problem will absolutely not grow outside of what I have posted, there will be no future expansions that I should consider.

I am using c++17 and have no problem with 3rd party libraries as long as they've not got restrictive licenses.

Comment: [`multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) or [`unordered_multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)

Comment: Use your garden-variety `std::multimap`, with the values being `std::shared_ptr`s to the object for that key. Each of a particular object's keys have a `std::shared_ptr` to the same object. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Aha, that is a neat solution. Thanks to both of you! Who wants to add this as a proper answer?

Answer (score 1):

Simply transcribing your requirements into a container: you want to go from an `Enum` to a bunch of `MyClass` objects:

```
map<Enum, vector<MyClass>>
```

Though that's not quite right, since you really want to potentially share `MyClass` objects amongst multiple keys. So:

```
map<Enum, vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>>
```

This'll get the job done, but you might have questions about performance. If your `Enum` values are all `[0, n-1)`, and performance becomes an issue, it might be worth simply wrapping a `vector`:

```
class CustomMap {
    std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> elems;

public:
    CustomMap() {
        elems.resize(n);
    }

    std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>& operator[](Enum e) {
        return elems[static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(e)];
    }

    // etc.
};
```

And then of course, `shared_ptr` really isn't right for the job either - you probably want to have a `vector<MyClass*>` such that the `CustomMap` separately manages them, etc. There's a lot more rabbit holes you can go down, depending on where you want to go.

Comment: Great answer with various caveats and options covered. Thanks!